# Eclipselink and ArrayMapping JPA problem

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have problem extracting data of the Oracle custom type from the database.
One of the columns in the table is of the Oracle custom type (which is actually VARRAY):

Here is create statement for this type:
`create or replace TYPE CAlarmMessList AS VARRAY(15) OF CAlarmMess;`

Where `CAlarmMess` is the following:
`create or replace TYPE CAlarmMess AS OBJECT (EreignisTypId NUMBER(9), EreignisKlasseId NUMBER(9), AlarmZeit DATE, ParamWert1 VARCHAR2(65 CHAR), ParamWert2 VARCHAR2(65 CHAR), ParamWert3 VARCHAR2(65 CHAR) [....]`

And the field I need has name `ALARME` and type `CALARMMESSLIST`.
I generated Entity for the table (`WSENSORSTATE`) using Oracle tools for Eclipse. This field was generated as `Object` field.
I manually created java type `CAlarmMess` with fields:

```
private BigDecimal ereignisTypId;  
private BigDecimal ereignisKlasseId;  
private Date alarmZeit;  
private String paramWert1;  
private String paramWert2;  
private String paramWert3;
```

And changed type of the field in my Entity to List of CAlarmMess.
When I added customizer for my entity:

`@Customizer(com.companyname.entities.WsensorstateCustomizer.class)`

Where customize method is the following:

> public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) throws Exception {
>   ObjectArrayMapping arrayMapping = new ObjectArrayMapping();
>
> arrayMapping.setReferenceClass(Wsensorstate.class);
>   arrayMapping.setAttributeName("alarme");
>   arrayMapping.setFieldName("CAlarmMess");
>   arrayMapping.setStructureName("CAlarmMessList");
>
> descriptor.addMapping(arrayMapping);
>   }

Now it falls with following error:
Exception [EclipseLink-197] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The mapping [alarme] is not the appropriate type for this descriptor
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.structures.ObjectArrayMapping[alarme]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.companyname.entities.Wsensorstate --> [DatabaseTable(WSENSORSTATE)])

I tried to add @StructConverter for the CAlarmMess but it also didn't work.

All suggestion will be appreciated, I already spent too much time working on it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a WsensorstateCustomizer customizer I assume set on the Wsensorstate entity, but the mapping you are adding is set to reference Wsensorstate.class.  This is telling EclipseLink that you are trying to build an array/collection of Wsensorstate, which isn't allowed as Wsensorstate is an entity with a RelationalDescriptor.  Instead, you will have to create a java class for the CAlarmMess structure so that you get a collection of CAlarmMess objects in your Wsensorstate entity.  Or you can map the alarme directly to a VARRAY and deal with the Oracle object yourself, but I'd go with the previous approach.

You will need to build an ObjectRelationalDataTypeDescriptor for the CAlarmMess java class as I do not know if this is exposed through the JPA interface, much like you are building the ObjectArrayMapping.  A simple example from the EclipseLink automated tests is:

```
    ObjectRelationalDataTypeDescriptor descriptor = new ObjectRelationalDataTypeDescriptor();
    // SECTION: DESCRIPTOR
    descriptor.setJavaClass(Phone.class);
    Vector vector = new Vector();
    vector.addElement("PolicyHolders");
    descriptor.setTableNames(vector);

    // SECTION: PROPERTIES
    descriptor.descriptorIsAggregate();

    descriptor.setStructureName("PHONE_TYPE");
    descriptor.addFieldOrdering("PHONETYPE");
    descriptor.addFieldOrdering("AREACODE");
    descriptor.addFieldOrdering("PHONENUMBER");

    descriptor.addDirectMapping("type", "getType", "setType", "PHONETYPE");
    descriptor.addDirectMapping("areaCode", "getAreaCode", "setAreaCode", "AREACODE");
    descriptor.addDirectMapping("number", "getNumber", "setNumber", "PHONENUMBER");
```

Which will need to be added to the session in a session customizer before it can be used by the ObjectArrayMapping.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Chris. Where should I place this ObjectRelationalDataTypeDescriptor? How to add it to session? And how to get it in ObjectArrayMapping? Another question: CAlarmMess isn't an entity class, how should I work with it (some annotations etc.)?

Comment: Ok, I created session customizer as you told me and added it to the session. How to use it in ObjectArrayMapping?

Comment: @Chris I'm not sure if you were notified about my previous comments, but it could be nice of you to answer. You're the only person ready to help me, and I really need this help :)

Comment: Other way around. You use the session customizer to create an ObjectRelationalDataTypeDescriptor for a java representation of your CAlarmMess struct. You would then add this to the session, so that other descriptors can map to it - so that your arrayMapping you set up in the descriptor customizer can then call

Comment: <continued> setReferenceClass(CAlarmMess.class);   You will probably need to mark the alarme attribute as transient in annotations so it doesn't get processed. As the CAlarmMess java class wouldn't be an entity, it shouldn't have JPA annotations on it.

Comment: One more question, @Chris, if it's not a problem. I did as you said, finally I created descriptor customizer. ObjectArrayMapping requires class descriptor to be an aggregate collection, so I called descriptorIsAggregateCollection(), after that all other mapings (which require normal class descriptor) seems to be lost. Do you have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: remove the descriptorIsAggregateCollection() - you want to put it on the reference descriptor, not the owning descriptor.  This method indicates that the objects do not have their own Identity, which is why your primary key info is being lost once it is set.